# Persistent USB mode for elementary OS Loki

Tags: release-loki

Greetings to all experienced elementary OS users. Just a question from a noob - how do I make elementary OS persistent on my USB drive? Here are some things I tried (and failed):

1) Installing elementary OS onto another USB drive (from a USB drive running on live mode) - when booting into the installed USB drive, I got a missing device error

2) Mounting the drive, going to the /boot directory and editing boot.cfg - I can't seem to find this file. Am I missing something?

Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I used Unetbootin with reasonable success, however I did have to edit syslinux.cfg to include "persistent" in the startup line.